# single line comments on external css file

Tags: css

I want to know whether external css files has single line comments or not.

I am using an external css file(styles.css) and i want to use single line comments in that file.I have tried using "//", "#", "--" but none of them worked.I know we can use "/*.....Comments here....*/" in single line but in my case I have to use single line commands. please help.

## style.css

```css
//{ strarBlock
.user-title {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #c1bd9e;
    margin-top: -3px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
.......
//} endBlock

//{ strarBlock
.user-details {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #c1bd9e;
    margin-top: -3px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
.......
//} endBlock
```

Comment: It's /* ---- */

Comment: Thanks @Goombah for your reply. I have edited my question do  external style sheet has any single line comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single line comments in CSS are single line comments:

`/* single line comments */`

There's no other way.

But you still can use a pseudo vendor prefix to comment properties:

```
.sample {
    -commented-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam for your answer. Could you please explain or suggest a link about "pseudo vendor prefix" and can we use that for any text also..

Comment: you can read more about vendor prefix here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix You can use this feature to prefix any property with you own vendor prefix (like "-commented-" in this example, this will be ignored by browsers)

Comment: Thanks @Adam. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a preprocessor to remove the `//` comments:

- https://github.com/mummybot/postcss-strip-inline-comments
- https://github.com/moczolaszlo/postcss-inline-comment
- https://github.com/lydell/strip-css-singleline-comments